# Arr.includes(item) - Can I Use with a Multidimensional Array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use the arr.includes(item). The function should return True if the item is an element of the array. But it doesn't seem to be able to do so with a multidimensional array. Take a look at this screenshot (running node in the console):

[image]

I got a similar result on my Google Chrome.

Is it because it's an EC6 function, and not yet completely functional?

No information on such a problem on the [Mozille page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control).

Comment: nope, because `includes()` compares by identity, not by (some) equality. check this: `[0,1] === [0,1]` this ain't true either.

Comment: You will have to use a combination of `array.some` + `array.every`

Comment: Array.includes() will not work in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't use it on deep structures, because it performs an `===` test that checks that the operands are the *same* object, and not two (different) objects that happen to have the same contents.

On the MDN page you linked to there's a polyfill where you can see that `===` test within the `sameValueZero()` nested function.

For the above reasons, this would actually return true:

```
let a = [0, 1];
let b = [1, 2];
let c = [a, b];
c.includes(b);
> true
```

because the object passed to `.includes` really *is* the same object that's contained in `c`.

Comment: So if my understanding is correct, it has to do with array being a reference/address, and what I'm actually passing to the function is an address.

Comment: @Ben pretty much yes, although of course JS doesn't actually given you any visibility of the address / reference.